# Running Kubectl inside a worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I did an SSH on a worker node inside the cluster and I run `kubectl` in there. I created a PV, a PVC and a deployment. I read on the documentation that PV is a cluster-wide object. My question is what happens in this case? In other words, Does running `kubectl` inside a worker node has the same effect as running it from master node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes. `kubectl` connects to the configured API server which controls the whole cluster.